# Can this be simplified to load multiple scripts in order

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following works but I need to distribute it to clients that may be uncomfortable of pasting all this script into their home page.  Just wondering if it can be simplified?  I need to load Jquery 1.71, then the UI and then my own script and then call the function in my own script.  Even minimized its rather long.

Hope some javascript guru can help.  Thanks!

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js';
script.type = 'text/javascript';
head.appendChild(script);
if (script.onreadystatechange) script.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (script.readyState == "complete" || script.readyState == "loaded") {
        script.onreadystatechange = false;
        //alert("complete");
        load_script();
    }
} else {
    script.onload = function () {
        //alert("complete");
        load_script();
    }
}
//setup array of scripts and an index to keep track of where we are in the process
var scripts = ['script/jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.min.js', 'script/wfo171.js'],
    index = 0;
//setup a function that loads a single script
function load_script() {
    //make sure the current index is still a part of the array
    if (index < scripts.length) {
        //get the script at the current index
        $.getScript('http://mydomainn.com/script/' + scripts[index], function () {
            //once the script is loaded, increase the index and attempt to load the next script
            //alert('Loaded: ' + scripts[index] + "," + index);
            if (index != 0) {
                LoadEdge();
            }
            index++;
            load_script();
        });
    }
}

function LoadEdge() {
    Edge('f08430fa2a');
}
```

Comment: Belongs on: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don;t you just use an onload event to make sure everything is loaded before trying to execute?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://mydomainn.com/script/jquery-ui-1.8.7.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://mydomainn.com/script/wfo171.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() { // this executes when the page is ready
        Edge('f08430fa2a');
    });
</script>
```

(check the paths on the scripts, you seem to be loading from `/script/script`, wasn't sure if that was correct so I removed it.

Answer (score 4):

As soon as you have jQuery you can use its power:

```
$.when.apply($, $.map(scripts, $.getScript)).then(LoadEdge);
```

This relies on its deferred functionality - each URL is replaced with a `getScript` deferred (this will fetch the script), and these deferreds are then passed to `$.when` so that you can add a callback using `.then` to be called when all scripts have finished loaded.

Comment: interesting. does this mean that jquery modifies the prototype of array and adds map? i thought they were against modifying native objects

Comment: @mkoryak: No, `.map` is native as well. You can also use `$.map` for legacy browsers which do not have this function on arrays - I will modify my answer.

Comment: @pimvdb I am going to try this, like the simplicity. one moment please.